# Is this recursive Tower of Hanoi Algorithm a type of uninformed search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, recursion, depth-first-search

```
void Form(int N, char pegA, char pegB, char pegC) {
    if (N == 1)
        cout<<"move top disk on peg "<<pegA<<" to peg"<<pegC<<endl;
    else {
        Form(N-1, pegA, pegC, pegB);
        cout<<"move top disk on peg "<<pegA<<" to peg"<<pegC<<endl;
        Form(N-1, pegB, pegA, pegC); 
    }
}
```

This is a recursive algorithm for the Tower of Hanoi Game. Can this be a form of depth-first search? If not, what is it?  thanks

Comment: Yes, this is depth-first search. The vertices of the graph are the states of the puzzle (i.e. number of disks, source peg, destination peg and the 'intermediate' peg). Two vertices (states) share an edge if one can be achieved for the other by moving one disk. The graph is actually a directional binary tree. So it has no cycle and this algorithm works.

Comment: @0605002: except that the unconstrained graph does have cycles. The algorithm (in effect) constrains each disk to always move in the same direction: even-numbered disks rotate clockwise and odd-numbered disks rotate counter-clockwise.

Comment: what search? there is no search here, no trying out, no backtracking. the solution is readily given. do this, then do that, then do the other. done!

Comment: IOW if this is a search then it is extremely informed, and does just the one right thing right away. "search" would try all possibilities of moving a disk.

Comment: @0605002 But the algorithm finds the best route to the goal state. Don't depth first searches start from the left deepest node and check everything recursively?

Comment: @WillNess Yeah that's what confused me It does not go through any node that is not on the goal path. What is this algorithm?

Comment: I would call this algorithm "the recursive Towers of Hanoi solution".  I don't think it needs any other names.

Comment: simply "recursion". or perhaps better, "structural recursion". cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a depth first search.

It is a recursive tree <strike>traversal</strike>... dive?

The logic of which move to make is built into the algorithm, and it cleverly uses recursion to handle each sub-tower transition.  There is no searching here.

The algorithm works in the following way

- End of recursion:

  - when there is one disk remaining, move it to the destination peg
  - this is the end of each sub-tower move
- Recursive logic:

  - move all disks above the one we are interested in to another peg
  - output the move command for the disk we are interested in
  - move all the disks we moved before on top of the disk we just moved.

The way it does this, is by the clever (and confusing) manipulation of the peg references.  it remaps which are the source and destination pegs when it makes the second recursive call.

Another thing to note:

There is no persistent state in this algorithm. The only state each layer cares about is the state of `n` and only then if it is 1 or not.  On function entry, the state of the current layer (on start peg) and all layers above (also on start peg) is known and the state of any disks below the current is unneeded.

This is why nothing needs to actually be moved; as the state is known, the knowledge about the changes in state can be encoded into the algorithm  (and are, by the changed order of the pegs passed into the recursive calls). There is no need to base decisions off the current state, and so no need to effect a state.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was wondering, would it ever get to the `cout` statement in the `else` condition? is that statement, and the one below it, even necessary?

Comment: The else clause does all the work. The If clause handles the "top disk" situation. The first recursive call "moves" all the disks on top of the current one off of it. The cout line prints the move of the current disk, and the second recursive call moves them all onto the the disk we just moved to complete the puzzle. The fun thing is that this is all virtual - we never actually move anything, or even create disks to move. Whenever we enter the function, the current disk and all smaller ones are in a known state - all in the correct order on the first provided peg, so no state is required.

Comment: @Wagari if you are having trouble visualising it, work through the algorithm on paper (following the commands that would be output) starting with n=1.  By the time you have done it with 3, you should have it.  If it helps, imagine two new functions: `move_smaller_off ()` and `move_smaller_on ()`. These functions will do nothing but call `Form ()` passing on their parameters in turn, but should help you reason about what is happening.

Comment: according to the `N == 1` case, `pegA` is the source and `pegC` is the target. Why are you saying that target is not defined? It's confusing and not clear what do you mean by that.

Comment: @WillNess you are right.  that's my mistake.  Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a depth-first search, because we know which move to make each time, so there's no choice. You can think about it that way. Nothing more than that.

Look, in the case of *Depth first search*, what do we do? We go deeper and *try* to find the correct way to go. But here, can you show me one move that was unnecessary? There isn't any.

So this is a simple *recursive* approach, where we solve *smaller* instances of the problem, and then *construct* the solution for the *larger* one, simply, from the smaller ones' results. That's it.

Comment: Doesn't the knowing which branch to take each time make it informed?

Comment: Yes..that's precisely is...it is informed. @Wagari

Comment: a tree with a branching factor of 1 is not a tree. hence, there 's no search. the solution is *constructed*, not *found*.

Comment: Ah..I just told the extreme case..yes it is a line towards the destination. Not tree but isn't that is something I mentioned here.

Comment: @WillNess.: Thanks and yes  I guess instead of over-simplifying I should have written it formally.